# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed:

Tags: java

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
> superclass access check failed: class common.FixedCachedRowSetImpl (in
> unnamed module @0x372dc8e2) cannot access class
> com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl (in module java.sql.rowset) because
> module java.sql.rowset does not export com.sun.rowset to unnamed
> module @0x372dc8e2    at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)    at
> java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
> at ffm.FFmDbConnection.dbSelectSQL2(FFmDbConnection.java:224)   at
> ffm.FFmUser.getLogInUserInfo(FFmUser.java:442)    at
> dialog.DlgLogInMES.checkUserInfo(DlgLogInMES.java:444)    at
> dialog.DlgLogInMES.funcLogIn(DlgLogInMES.java:276)    at
> dialog.DlgLogInMES.access$0(DlgLogInMES.java:271)     at
> dialog.DlgLogInMES$1.actionPerformed(DlgLogInMES.java:96)     at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:191)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:236)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234)
> at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:234)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1080)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1728)     at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1675)   at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1036)     at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1016)     at
> dialog.DlgLogInMES.showDialog(DlgLogInMES.java:399)   at
> fopismes.iOPISmain.loadLogInDialog(iOPISmain.java:223)    at
> fopismes.iOPISmain.access$0(iOPISmain.java:209)   at
> fopismes.iOPISmain$1.run(iOPISmain.java:129)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:771)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:741)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Comment: `CachedRowSet rows = new FixedCachedRowSetImpl(); ` 

 Changed this to this ->
      
`CachedRowSet rows = RowSetProvider.newFactory().createCachedRowSet();`

It will work but then bunch of errors will come out after changing this code line.

Comment: So this was not the exact solution. i have 2 teammates and both of them work fine with this project. I have installed latest Eclipse and changed JDK exact same as their JDK. But still NOT working for me.